# Cannot connect to rust kernel from a jupyter server in a conda env

Tags: rust, jupyter, conda, rustup

I have been trying to install a Rust kernel for a Jupyter server inside a dedicated conda environment but I get errors.

Slighty adjusting steps from:
https://depth-first.com/articles/2020/09/21/interactive-rust-in-a-repl-and-jupyter-notebook-with-evcxr/

1. `conda create -n rusttest`
2. `conda activate rusttest`
3. `conda install -c conda-forge rust jupyterlab`
4. `conda install -c anaconda cmake -y`
5. `cargo install evcxr_jupyter`
6. Add `$HOME/.cargo/bin` to my PATH variable (export PATH)
7. `evcxr_jupyter --install` (here I already see the kernel is installed outside the env)
8. `jupyter lab`

The kernel is visible on the dashboard however when I try to start a notebook with it the connection fails and I get:

> Error: Failed to find sysroot for Cargo.toml file /tmp/.tmpbZ0Pkw/Cargo.toml. Is rust-src installed?

I have tried manually:

```
jupyter kernelspec install {MY_PATH_DURING_PKG_INSTALLATION}/Jupyter/kernels/rust --sys-prefix
```

And I get:

```
[InstallKernelSpec] Installed kernelspec rust in {MY_PATH}/miniconda3/envs/rusttest/share/jupyter/kernels/rust
```

Which seems OK (inside the correct conda env) but the error persists.

Is there any way to add a working kernel just to this one jupyter server inside that env?
(I want Rust to be gone when I start `jupyter lab` from another conda env)

##### EDIT

After digging into this I think the first thing is to get `rust-src` installed inside that conda environment... I don't know how...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved:

I needed to download `https://static.rust-lang.org/dist/2022-05-19/rust-src-1.61.0.tar.gz` manually and extract it under the env dir such that `XXX/miniconda3/envs/rusttest/lib/rustlib/src/rust` exists.

Comment: Thank you, could you please put link for other distributions beside 1.61?

Comment: try looking at their .toml files by version such as http://static.rust-lang.org/dist/channel-rust-1.13.0.toml or http://static.rust-lang.org/dist/channel-rust-1.67.1.toml etc.
(ref: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-forge/issues/215#issuecomment-488328424)

Answer (score 0):

I had installed rust (which installs rustc and cargo) like so:

```
conda activate my_env
conda install rust=1.67.1 -c conda-forge
```

you may be able to just install rust-src as such (but I haven't tried yet) - but it is a package https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/rust-src/files:

```
conda activate my_env
conda install rust-src=1.67.1 -c conda-forge
```

Alternatively, a more programatic take on @maciek's answer:

try looking at their .toml files by version such as http://static.rust-lang.org/dist/channel-rust-1.13.0.toml or http://static.rust-lang.org/dist/channel-rust-1.67.1.toml etc. and find the rust-src download link
(ref: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-forge/issues/215#issuecomment-488328424)

We can do this part programatically too:

```bash
brew tap 4rbor/tq && brew install tq
wget http://static.rust-lang.org/dist/channel-rust-1.67.1.toml
RUST_SRC_URL=$(tq -f channel-rust-1.67.1.toml 'pkg.rust-src.target.*.url')
```

Then:

```bash
cd ~/miniconda/envs/my_env/
wget -c $RUST_SRC_URL -O - | tar -xz
cp -r rust-src-1.67.1/rust-src/lib/rustlib lib
```