# How do I get Codebook to run Rust (installed by conda) in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, rust-analyzer

I have installed Anaconda 3 and VS Code on Windows 10. I am interested in running Rust in a notebook, and I found [CodeBook](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=codebook.codebook) which seemed to fit the bill. I installed Rust using conda in an environment `conda create -n rust_env -c conda-forge rust`, and then installed the `rust-analyzer` extension in VS Code and created a markup document which I opened in CodeBook.

However, when I try to run a cell, I find that `rust-analyzer` has scanned 0 of 0 roots and "failed to load workspace 'cargo' - program not found".

If I activate the `rustenv` using conda in the terminal I can run `cargo --version`, but it seems that CodeBook is not running Rust in the right environment. Any idea how I can set this?

I cannot find any help in the rust-analyzer manual:
https://rust-analyzer.github.io/manual.html

VS Code showing conda environment in terminal

[image: First errors on start-up]

[image: "The Rust Analyzer Language Server server crashed 5 times in the last 3 minutes."]

[image: Analyzer client references non-existent directory]

UPDATE: I have added the rust executables to the path:
`C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\rustenv\Library\bin`

Now there are server errors...

```
[Info  - 2:10:43 pm] Connection to server got closed. Server will restart.
[Error - 2:10:43 pm] Server initialization failed.
  Message: Pending response rejected since connection got disposed
  Code: -32097 
[Error - 2:10:43 pm] Rust Analyzer Language Server client: couldn't create connection to server.
  Message: Pending response rejected since connection got disposed
  Code: -32097 
[Error - 2:10:43 pm] Restarting server failed
  Message: Pending response rejected since connection got disposed
  Code: -32097 
[Info  - 2:10:45 pm] Connection to server got closed. Server will restart.
[Error - 2:10:45 pm] Server initialization failed.
  Message: Pending response rejected since connection got disposed
  Code: -32097 
[Error - 2:10:45 pm] Rust Analyzer Language Server client: couldn't create connection to server.
  Message: Pending response rejected since connection got disposed
  Code: -32097 
[Error - 2:10:45 pm] Restarting server failed
  Message: Pending response rejected since connection got disposed
  Code: -32097 
[Error - 2:10:45 pm] The Rust Analyzer Language Server server crashed 5 times in the last 3 minutes. The server will not be restarted. See the output for more information.
```

I don't understand what this means...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience is that, unfortuneately, VS Code does not work nice with conda for rust. You will have to change settings in multiple places and I actually never got it to work myself.

It is better to install rust on your system without conda, and then everything in VS Code works out of the box.

- In your case, on Windows, you would install with [rustup-init.exe](https://forge.rust-lang.org/infra/other-installation-methods.html)
- For those on Linux/Mac, you would install with [rustup](https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install)

Answer (score 3):

I recently got rust and rust-analyzer working in a conda environment, it was a bit of a pain, so up to you if you think it is worth it or not.

I wrote about it here: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-analyzer/issues/14477#issuecomment-1506098692

And copying the info here:

It took quite a few steps. I have not determined concretely if all of these are needed but certainly most of them are:

- add conda env to path (for me in `.zshrc`) and/or just `conda activate zzz` in the same file
- downloading/installing rust-src into my conda env, which is not included as part of the conda rust install (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76000140/9792594)
- add `export RUST_SRC_PATH="/Users/xxx/miniconda/envs/zzz/lib/librust/src/rust/src"` also to `.zshrc`

for reference I have:

- MacOS 13.3.1 (22E261)
- conda=23.1.0
- rust=1.67.1
- `cargo --version = cargo 1.67.1 (8ecd4f20a 2023-01-10)`
- `rustc --version = rustc 1.67.1 (d5a82bbd2 2023-02-07)`
- `~/.vscode/extensions/rust-lang.rust-analyzer-0.3.1472-darwin-arm64/server/rust-analyzer --version = rust-analyzer 0.3.1472-standalone (01120f121 2023-04-07)`

Comment: Thanks! This is probably not the answer for me as I am running Windows, but I hope it will be helpful to others. I may also try it at home where I have a Mac.

Comment: I imagine it will be quite similar on Windows. I have a Windows 10 machine I can try it on (which has conda environments installed on it). It probably just requires adding the conda env to the path in .bashrc or similar.